# I have two types of Errors in Blazor Server that appear in razor.g.cs files (upgrading to preview 9)

Tags: blazor-server-side

I created a preview 9 server blazor project and attempted to convert an existing preview 6 to it, Using a guide that is public in the internet. I get two types of errors (35 errors) that appears in razor.g.cs files:

Error   CS1662  Cannot convert lambda expression to intended delegate type because some of the return types in the block are not implicitly convertible to the delegate return type BlazorStore9    C:...\obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\Razor\Pages\Admin\EditProductComponents\AddEditProductDescriptionImage.razor.g.cs

**and**

Error   CS1503  Argument 6: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.EventCallback'  BlazorStore9    C:...\obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\Razor\Pages\Admin\EditProductComponents\AddEditProductDescriptionImage.razor.g.cs    326 Active

I managed to solve all the errors (thousands) based on that guide, but finally stop here, how do I solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved:
The error raised because new Radzen file input version expects a TValue="string" attribute for setting up its callback.